# Chrome webdriver failed to start after updating selenium jars

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I was using selenium-server-standalone 3.7.1, html runner 3.7.1.

Recently updated these with 3.8.1 and 3.8 versions. after updating am getting error. Here are the logs

```
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.is(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.init(RemoteWebDriver.java:176)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:112)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
        at com.Pype.AutoSpecs.AddProjectFlowTest.AutospecsSeleniumAddProjectFlowGCTest.addProjectFlowGCTest(AutospecsSeleniumAddProjectFlowGCTest.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate question?

Comment: I was using selenium-server-standalone 3.7.1, html runner 3.7.1. Recently updated these with 3.8.1 and 3.8 versions. after updating am getting this error

Comment: Please add these details to your question by editing it.

Comment: Just guessing here based on some recent experience, try updating your Guava libraries. Even if you don't have Guava as a dependency in pom, just add it (try version 21). This is all in case you use Maven of course.